# PDO "Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" yet it is

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Basically what I'm doing is a users class, which executes a MySQL query in the constructor to retrieve all the users data and store it, like so:

```
public function __construct($data, $type = 'id')
{
    $this->details = Beam::$db->row("SELECT * FROM users WHERE $type = :param", ['param' => $data]);
    if(!empty($this->details)) $this->exists = true;
}
```

**This is row() method:**

```
public function row($query, $params = null, $fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
{
    $this->init($query, $params);
    return $this->statementQuery->fetch($fetchmode);
}
```

**And init(), where the parameters are bound and the query is executed:**

```
public function init($query, $parameters = '')
    {
        try {
                $this->statementQuery = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

                if(!empty($parameters))
                {
                    foreach($parameters as $key => $value)
                    {
                        $this->bind($key, $value);
                    }
                }

                if(!empty($this->parameters))
                {
                    foreach($this->parameters as $key => &$value)
                    {
                        $this->statementQuery->bindParam($key, $value);
                    }
                }

                $this->success = $this->statementQuery->execute();

            }

        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            throw new SystemException($e->getMessage() . ' in query: ' . $query, (int) $e->getCode());
        }

        $this->parameters = array();
    }
```

It should work, I've tested everything multiple times, and debugged using dies() everywhere, but it seems as if I instantiate the class more than one time, the error occurs. It's called multiple times in all my code. Is there something I'm missing?

**The error:**

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :param
```

I've also tried debugging printing all the parameters set in PDO by `::debugDumpParams()`, and all the parameters are okay, I even var_dump the `$this->statementQuery->fetch($fetchmode)` from the `row()` method and it returns everything as it should be...

**PS: I bind the array ['param' => $data] afterwards, using this method:**

```
    public function bind($param, $value)
    {
        $this->parameters[':' . $param] = $value;
    }
```

Some examples of where I call the class from:

**Login method. Called when the user does login. It fails.**

```
public static function login($user, $password)
    {
        $user = new User($user, Beam::$con->auth['type']);

            if($user->exists == true)
            {
                $user_ip       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $user_browser  = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $user_id       = $user->details["id"];
                $username      = $user->details["username"];
                $user_mail     = $user->details["mail"];
                $user_password = $user->details["password"];

                if(self::verify($password, $user_password))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_id']       = $user_id;
                    $_SESSION['username']      = $username;
                    $_SESSION['user_mail']     = $user_mail;
                    $_SESSION['user_checksum'] = hash('sha512', $user_password . $user_ip . $user_browser);

                    Beam::$db->bind("l", time());
                    Beam::$db->bind("u", $user_id);
                    Beam::$db->query("UPDATE user_info SET login_timestamp = :l WHERE user_id = :u");

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**This one checks if the user is logged in. It's called almost in every file for authenticated users only.**

```
public static function status()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"], $_SESSION["username"], $_SESSION["user_checksum"]))
        {
            $user = new User($_SESSION["user_id"], "id");

            if($user->exists)
            {
                $user_id          = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                $user_checksum    = $_SESSION['user_checksum'];
                $username         = $_SESSION['username'];
                $user_ip          = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $user_browser     = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $user_password    = $user->details["password"];

                switch($user_checksum)
                {
                    default:
                    $checksum_verify = hash('sha512', $user_password . $user_ip . $user_browser);
                    break;

                    case "facebook":
                    $checksum_verify = "facebook";
                    break;
                }

                if($checksum_verify == $user_checksum)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `['param'=>$data]` the same as `array('param'=>$data)`? Cause I am using the later with PDO in my code and it work fine.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same...

Comment: Ah! I'll go to bed less stupid tonight! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same name for the parameter that you used in the query. In this case you used ":param" so that's what you need to use when you pass in the array of parameters.

change

```
['param' => $data]
```

to

```
[':param' => $data]
```

and it should work.

Comment: I bind all the parameters from that array later like this: `$this->parameters[':' . $param] = $value;` So I do add the :

Comment: Can you include the code for where you are calling this from?

Comment: PDO will actually accept them with or without the `:` prefix.

Comment: I updated the post with some major methods that use this class. Other than these, I use it directly in files aswell, everytime I need to access to user data.

Comment: I don't know, but like I said, it's like if I call it more than once the error occurs, it's rather strange.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only other suggestion I can think of based on the information you provided is to find out why it's being called multiple times. My guess is that somewhere you have a parameter array that doesn't match with your query, but I don't see it in the methods you have provided. I would look for the ":param" string in your code to find it.

Comment: Why it's being called multiple times? I use it as a user object. Everytime I need to access user data, I do `$user = new User(whatever, whatever);` so that's why I use it multiple times. And there is only one parameter array that gets set with each query as I posted in the `init()` method. It feels like when I instantiate the class for the second time, the parameters dissapear, yet when I debug it, it shows me all of them. I've been like a week struggling with this issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a simpler test case? If so post the source somewhere so I can take a look at it and I'll see if I can figure it out. Alternatively you can post the source of your entire project, but that might not be an option.